# wordpress cant able to install any plugins showing error------ Installation failed: Download failed. No working transports found?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

In my wordpress when I trying to install any plugins it shows the error(Installation failed: Download failed. No working transports found).I enabled both curl and openssl in my server and also restarted server.But still the issue not resolved.I am using AWS server.Kindly help anyone.

Comment: can you change the "wp_debug" value to true?? so you can see the actual error

Comment: reffer this link may be it will help you.: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/292175/installation-failed-download-failed-no-working-transports-found

Comment: @ Darsh khakhkha refered your link tried all the steps but the same problem occurs.

Comment: did you set the wp_debug to true?

Comment: yes it shows the same error line in php file

Comment: it points to wp-includes\class-requests.php file.                                                  
 if (self::$transport[$cap_string] === null) {
   throw new Requests_Exception('No working transports found', 'notransport', self::$transports);
  }

Comment: its core file, so better not to touch it, may be you have some problem in you server config.

Comment: server config means apache (httpd.conf)? if so means,I configured that also properly.

Comment: you need to check your curl and php version also check if sockets are enable or not and have you restarted your server after following the steps in my previous comment?

Comment: yes restarterd my server after following steps.sockets means what?

Comment: curl version 7.54.0, php version PHP 7.0.20 (cli) and also enabled the sockets extension=php_sockets.dll in my php.ini but still same problem

Comment: problem solved.

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: Actually i cheked phpinfo through cmd,it shows as curl enabled.But when checked through browser it shows not enabled.So i moved required dll files to apache/bin folder then restarted it works.

Comment: It was mentioned in the answer i suggested though.... anyway happy to help..

Comment: look the answer by "Carel" in which there is a 'Check' section read it out..

Comment: ya i found it jus a min before u post thats y only i deleted the comment sry anyways thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Please add this to the  Apache config file:

```
 Below this line: #LoadModule xml2enc_module modules/mod_xml2enc.so
       # load curl and open ssl libraries
        LoadFile “C:\php\libeay32.dll”
        LoadFile “C:\php\ssleay32.dll”
        LoadFile “C:\php\libssh2.dll”

And above this line: <IfModule unixd_module>

Stop Apache server using : service httpd  stop
Start Apache server using: service httpd start
```

This should help.